# Find $(f \circ g)'$ given $f(u)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $f(u)=1-\frac{1}{u} \hspace{25pt} u=g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x} \hspace{25pt}
>  x= - 1$
>
> find the value of $(f \circ g)'$ at the given value of $x$.

$\underline{\text{Wrong method :}} \hspace{10pt}f(x) = 1-\frac{1}{1-x}\hspace{25pt} f'(x)=-\left(-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\cdot -1\right) = -\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

$\hspace{70pt}\therefore f'(-1) = -\frac{1}{(1-(-1))^2} = -\frac{1}{4}$

Correct method is finding $g(-1), g'(-1), f'(g(-1)) \text{and then} (f \circ g)'$ and the answer is $1$

What is wrong in the wrong method?

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))\implies(f\circ g)'(-1)=f'(g(-1))g'(-1)$. Also, $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: What is $f(x)$? The composition is $$f(g(x)) = 1 - \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-x}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong method seems to be wrong because you are differentiating a function ($f(x)$, which is essentially misleading here) that is not related at all with the composition $f \circ g$.
You can either apply the rule $(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$ or compute directly
$$
(f \circ g)(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-x}} = 1- (1-x) = x.
$$

Comment: x=-1 but the answer is 1

Comment: So what? I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Vikram The answer will always be $1$ here because $(f \circ g)'(x)=1$ is independent of $x$ (it's a constant function).

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that $f(x) \neq 1 - \frac{1}{1-x}$. If $f(u)=1-\frac{1}{u}$ and $u=g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ then $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-x}}=1-(1-x)=x$. So $(f \circ g)'=f(x)'=1$.

Comment: How is $f(x)=x$? It should be $f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x\implies f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: So $f(\frac{1}{1-x})=x$ if f is a function with variable u. If you you insert the function $g(x)=u(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ into $f(u)$, f becomes a function with variable x. So $f(x)=(f \circ g)(x)=x$.
The last implication in your comment is false. Left hand side is right, but the implication is not. What you're doing wrong is inserting u into x.

Comment: What happens if you replace $\frac{1}{1-x}\mapsto y$ in $f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x$? Then $f(y)=1-\frac{1}{y}$ don't you think?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you write $f(\frac{1}{1-x})=x$, what is the domain of f? That is, what is the variable of f?

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=x$ is true, but the question implies that $f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x$. Solving the functional equation gives $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$ where $x\neq 0$. For $f(x)$ to be equal to $x$, $g(x)$ has to be $x$ as well.